# Extending classes with new methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, extension-methods

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to know what is the best approach\choice to extend my classes with new methods. I am planning to implement new methods for editing stings to perform action as made by the module `ActiveSupport::Inflector`.

I thought to create a new file for that in the lib folder... then, how I should include that file to make it possible to call those methods in my controllers and models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only adding methods to the String class, monkey_patch it in a file within /lib:

```
class String

  def my_method
  end

end
```

But if you want to add other methods to a class:

- create a module
- create the methods in the module
- include the module in your class (it's a mixin)

Comment: How can I include that mixin in all my classes so that I can call its methods everywhere in my helper, controller and model files?

Comment: Hint: all classes inherit from the Object class.

Comment: If you include the mixin inside Object with monkey patching, all classes will get its methods.